# where did GMSPlacesClient.lookUpPhotosForPlaceID go?

Tags: ios, swift, api, photo, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm currently experimenting with the google places API on swift, following the official doc : https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/photos .

My app is already using successfully the google maps api (so no installation problem), now I'm trying to fetch photos of a given place, using the provided sample code.
However, it would seem that the lookUpPhotosForPlaceID simply does not exist anymore... XCode shows the following error :

> Value of type 'GMSPlacesClient' has no member 'lookUpPhotosForPlaceID'

on the line

```
  GMSPlacesClient.sharedClient().lookUpPhotosForPlaceID(placeID) { (photos, error) -> Void in
```

Same for the loadPlacePhoto function called afterwards!

If anyone has any idea has for why this thing doesn't work, I would greatly appreciate it !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an engineer on the Places API for iOS team.

Sorry about this. We released a version (1.12.0) of the SDK with this feature, but noticed some problems and rolled it back in version 1.12.1. We now have a new release out which fixes the issue and adds lookUpPhotosForPlaceID. If you upgrade to version 1.12.2, you should see it again.

Comment: Indeed, I just updated to 1.12.2, my function is back and after a little experimentation, it would seem that everything works perfectly ! Having tested it on Android, I have to say, it's fare easier to use on iOS !

Comment: @jamie-McCloskey, what could be a reason for GMSPlacesClient not returning photos for a place? if I search this place in google maps, it definitely has photos